# Byte formate in avro

Tags: oracle11g, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

How can I stop the conversion of number into byte formate while loading Oracle table into Kafka using confluent 5.0.0.? The conversion to byte is creating a lot of issues while reusing the data in broker. Is there a way to convert byte format to decimal in vertica db directly?

More details:
Everytime I send a table from oracle to Kafa the number type converts into byte and date converts into long. When I load the data into vertica using KafkaSource and KafkaAvroParser, the data doesn't get decoded back.

Is there a way I can edit the schema formate in schema-registry in confluent 5.0.0

Details:

curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-oracle-jdbc-EMP1-value/versions/1

{"subject":"test-oracle-jdbc-EMP1-value","version":1,"id":2,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"EMP1\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"EMPNO\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":0,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"0\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}},{\"name\":\"ENAME\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"JOB\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"MGR\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":0,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"0\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"HIREDATE\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"long\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"SAL\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":2,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"2\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"COMM\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":2,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"2\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"DEPTNO\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":0,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"0\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"EMP1\"}"}

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the components you're using? Is this a custom producer, or a Kafka Connect Connector? If it's a Connector, which one? What serializers are you using? It sounds like you need to read up a bit more on how data is written to Kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html

Comment: I am using the JDBC connector to connect to oracle. The serializer here is KafkaAvroSerializer.

Comment: Kafka connect via Confluent.

Comment: For more clarity: You're using the JDBC source connector to connect to Oracle, and then using the JDBC sink connector to attempt to write that data to Vertica? This shouldn't be an issue. Please provide schemas/DDL for the source and sink tables, also include your connect worker configs for both the source and the sink. We can't help you if you don't provide more details.

Comment: I am just a beginner for Kafka but I guess that the KafkaAvroSerializer along with the schema registry where the schema exist convert my table into avro format where I get the number type converted into byte and date to long when when consumed by consumer is always in byte and long formate. My consumer is vertica so I can't restore the original format after consuming the data in vertica.

Comment: Please provide the schema from the schema registry for the topic that the JDBC connector is producing to: `curl schema-registry:8081/subjects/topic-name-value/versions/1`.

Comment: curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-oracle-jdbc-EMP1-value/versions/1

{"subject":"test-oracle-jdbc-EMP1-value","version":1,"id":2,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"EMP1\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"EMPNO\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":0,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"0\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}},{\"name\":\"ENAME\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"JOB\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"MGR\",\"type\":[\"

Comment: null\",{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":0,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"0\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"HIREDATE\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"long\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"SAL\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"scale\":2,\"precision\":64,\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"scale\":\"2\"},\"connect.name\":\"org.a

Comment: This is the details of my schema

Comment: These aren't readable here, plus they were cut off. Please edit your original question to include them.

Comment: Please also add your Connect Source properties, but in general `"logicalType":"decimal"` should be doing the conversion even though the type if bytes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the JDBC source connector, you can set

```
"numeric.mapping":"best_fit"
```

in your connector configuration.

See [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/5.1.0/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html#database) and [this blog](https://rmoff.net/2018/05/21/kafka-connect-and-oracle-data-types/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Robin is correct about the numeric mapping. As for the date showing up in as long, that is a timestamp in milliseconds. To convert that value to a Vertica `TIMESTAMP`, divide the number by 1,000 and then cast it as a timestamp.

To use `HIREDATE` as an example, you would do the following:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(HIREDATE / 1000) ...
```